# Game Center bugs

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

For a 3 days Game Center leaderboard shows sometimes 71 players total and sometimes 226 players total in my Game. 71 players total was 4 days ago. 226 players was 3 days ago. So I'm stuck with this 2 numbers for 3 days. A few people reported to me that their results was in Game Center and than disappear. It looks like forever. I have same issue. My result may disappear from Game Center after 30 minutes after reporting.

I have already reported bug to Apple. But maybe this kind of stuff is normal for Game Center? Or it's known issue that I could fix somehow?

Comment: Check out this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410846/unity-apple-game-center-ios7-registers-the-scores-for-only-30-minutes-in-the-le/25463724#25463724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by Apple.
See this thread: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1028533#1028533